# use Euclid's algorithm to find a matrices relation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, elementary-number-theory, determinant, gcd-and-lcm

> Let $$GL_2 = \left\{ A\in M_2(\mathbb{Z}\mid \det A \in \{\pm 1\} \right\}$$
>
> $$a = \left(\begin{array}{cc}
> 1 & 1\\
> 0 & 1
> \end{array}\right), b = \left(\begin{array}{cc}
> 0 & 1\\
> 1 & 0
> \end{array}\right)$$
>   Show using the Euclid's algorithm for GCD that for every $g\in GL_2$ there are $s_1,\ldots,s_k, r_1,\ldots,r_k$ such that $$g = a^{r_1}\cdots a^{r_k}b^{s_1}\cdots b^{s_k}$$

So we learned in class about the [matrix method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm#Matrix_method) for Euclid's algorithm. Also, I know that $\det A = ad-bc$ so in our case that means that $ad-bc = \pm 1$ which means that $\gcd (ad,bc) = 1$. In addition, I know that since $A$ is invertible then there are $E_1,\ldots,E_m$ such that $A = E_1\cdots E_m$.

I tried to connect the dots for those facts above, but couldn't put my finger on the solution.

I'd be glad for help!

Comment: Let $u = \left(\begin{array}{cc}A & B\\ C & D\end{array}\right)$ then find some $n$ such that $u a^{-n} b = \left(\begin{array}{cc}A_2 & B_2\\ - (D \bmod C) & C\end{array}\right)$ ie. one step of the $\gcd$ algorithm